# Why res.redirect('/') doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

I'm implementing a simple login/logout scenario using Express framework on Node.js. For the login I have no problems: on clicking "Login", after providing the correct username and password, the user is correctly redirected to the clientPage:

```
//POST route for logging in
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
if (req.body.logusername && req.body.logpassword) {

    User.authenticate(req.body.logusername, req.body.logpassword, function (error, user) {
      if (error || !user) {
        var err = new Error('Wrong email or password.');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
      } else {
        req.session.userId = user._id;
        return res.redirect('/clientPage');
      }
    });
  } else {
    var err = new Error('All fields required.');
    err.status = 400;
    return next(err);
  }
})

// GET route after registering
router.get('/clientPage', function (req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.session.userId)
    .exec(function (error, user) {
      if (error) {
        return next(error);
      } else {
        if (user === null) {
          var err = new Error('Not authorized! Go back!');
          err.status = 400;
          return next(err);
        } else {
          return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../views/clientPage.html'));
        }
      }
    });
});
```

The behaviour changes when logging out, even though the scenario is not that different: clicking on the "Log out" button in the client page, a "logout()" function is called, which makes an AJAX GET request to "/logout", handled by my routes script:

```
function logout(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/logout',
        async: true,
    })

}

// GET for logout
router.get('/logout', function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.session) {
    // delete session object
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      } else {
        return res.redirect('/');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

In the Network tab of my browser I see that the first request gets a "200 OK" response and successfully redirects the client to the given page, while the logout request results in "304 Not Modified" answer, containing in the response the page I want (the root, i.e. my homepage), but does not redirect the current page to the new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue arises because you are sending logout as an ajax request. This results in your ajax request being redirected, but not your page. What you want to do is to send the request directly from the page by setting a link on your logout button.

```
<a href="/logout">log out<a/>
```

This way, your whole page will be redirected.